# Magento + APC get data

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

First of all, i'm not familliar with apc. 
It's turned on on my site. And i've been faced next problem:
I need to get current page number in my custom block on products list page. But, when i input 
 `echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();`, i get same page number on all pages (i mean on pages with params /?p=2, /?p=3 it allways '1') untill i will clean apc cache. This number changes only after cleaning cache. Not on every page changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with APC configuration, because APC should renew the cache when the file has changed.

Comment: no. File is not changet between page refreshes. changes only current page number, but `echo` still displays same result

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can't be. (you know, these moments were... )

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php:87
public function getCurrentPage()
{
    if ($page = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getPageVarName())) {
        return $page;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The page is directly read from the request. So The only thing which comes in my mind is hooking into the method with xdebug and check what's wrong.

Comment: Most funny thing is that `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` returns also same array, no mater of page selected, or filter applied.

Comment: I mean. I insert `echo $this->getRequest()->getParams();` in my template on product list. Then i go via pager block link to the next page. And i expect, that in array will be changed paramether 'p'. But it doesn't. Then i reload apache (clean apc cache) and only then array changes.